# How to shutdown Net::LDAP::Server

Tags: linux, perl, service, ldap, application-shutdown

I have a Perl LDAP server which is based on the use
[`Net::LDAP::Server`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP::Server)
module.
To have it running as a service in Linux, I use the
[`Net::Server::PreForkSimple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server::PreForkSimple)
library.

So far everything works fine, but when I shut the service down the child processes don't close.

What is the correct way to shut down all processes?

When I send a `SIGTERM` signal, the `server_close` method is called but nothing else happens. From this point on, terminated children are no longer restarted, but the children waiting for work are not terminated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#chkconfig: 345 80 05
#description: LDAP Server for Innovaphone

use strict;
use warnings;

package Listener;

use Net::Server;
use base 'Net::Server::PreForkSimple';

my $continue = 1;

...

sub process_request {
    my $self = shift;

    my $in  = *STDIN{IO};
    my $out = *STDOUT{IO};

    my $sock         = $self->{server}->{client};
    my $peer_address = $sock->peerhost();
    my $peer_port    = $sock->peerport();
    logwarn( "Connection accepted from $peer_address : $peer_port" );

    my $handler = InnoLdapServer->new($sock);

    while ( 1 ) {
        my $finished = $handler->handle;
        return if $finished;
    }
}

...

sub server_close {
    logmsg( "Server close called" );
    $continue = 0;
}

# Start daemon
Proc::Daemon::Init();

my $pidfile = File::Pid->new({ file => "/var/run/inno-ldap.pid" });

if ( $pidfile->running() ) {
    die "Already running";
}

$pidfile->write();

open( STDOUT, '>', "$logpath/inno-ldap.$logName.log" ) or die "Can't open stdout log";
select( ( select( STDOUT ), $| = 1 )[0] );    # make the log file "hot" - turn off buffering

open( STDERR, '>', "$logpath/inno-ldap.$logName.error.log" ) or die "Can't open error log";
select( ( select( STDERR ), $| = 1 )[0] );    # make the log file "hot" - turn off buffering

while ( $continue ) {

    # package main;
    $roothandler = Listener->run(
        port          => [ 636, "389/tcp" ],
        proto         => "ssl",   # use ssl as the default
        ipv           => "*",     # bind both IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces
        user          => "daemon",
        group         => "daemon",
        SSL_key_file  => "/home/root/ssl_cert/server.pem",
        SSL_cert_file => "/home/root/ssl_cert/server.pem",
        max_servers   => 10,
        log_level     => 4
    );
}

$pidfile->remove();

1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown code doesn't deal with the `Net::Server` itself, ie. its `::PreForkSimple` extension; the server itself need be closed if the program is terminated by a signal. We can't see the calling code and how you "*shut the service down*," other than by the mentioned signal.

There is a `server_close` method in `Net::Server` for this. But the method of the same name that the question refers to seems to be the one in your `Listener` class, which thus overrides the (grand)parent's method. It only stops further work in child processes and doesn't touch the server.

So if that's the method called in the signal handler then the server never gets shut down properly and its existing children stay around. You need to call `server_close` on a `Net::Server` object, or to arrange in your own `server_close` method to call the parent's one.

The `Net::Server` documentation under the [Process Flow](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod#PROCESS-FLOW) explains

> During the server shutdown phase (`$self->server_close`), the following represents the program flow:
>
> ```
> $self->close_children;  # if any  
> $self->post_child_cleanup_hook;  
> if (Restarting server) {
>     $self->restart_close_hook();  
>     $self->hup_server;  
> }
>
> $self->shutdown_sockets;  
>
> $self->server_exit;
> ```

If the call to `server_close` on a `Net::Server` object or on the parent of your `Listener` object for some reason doesn't do it then try with individual methods listed in the workflow.

There are also signals listed in the
[Net::Server::PreForkSimple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server::PreForkSimple) "personality" under [Shutdown](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod#SHUTDOWN)

> Each of the Fork and PreFork personalities support graceful shutdowns via the QUIT signal. When a QUIT is received, the parent will signal the children and then wait for them to exit.

and then under [Hot Deploy](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod#SHUTDOWN)

> Since version 2.000, the PreForkSimple server has accepted the TTIN and TTOU signals. When a TTIN is received, the max_servers is increased by 1. If a TTOU signal is received the max_servers is decreased by 1

But I'd hope that this shouldn't be needed for shutting it down, and certainly not the last one.

Comment: @AndréSchild Updated with an explanation (and other minor edits)

Comment: Removing the `sub server_close` code got the desired result, along with removing the loop in the `while ($continue)` loop.

Comment: @AndréSchild Great.  That is the simplest way to let `Net::Server::server_close` be called, by not overriding it. (I didn't see the purpose of the `while ($continue)` loop either but didn't bring that up as there is clearly more code in reality.)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `while (1)` loop to `while ($pidfile->running())` in `process_request` should do the trick. Setting `$continue` to zero prevents any more Listeners from running but from what I can tell, the `process_request` subroutine ignores that variable.

Of course, this will need `$pidfile` to be declared earlier as it wouldn't be in scope in `process_request` since it was declared (and assigned) after the subroutine definition.

Comment: This does not close the child processes, I think we would need to signal TERM to each forked child to get the desired result